# Proving that the free abelian group $G$ for the set $\mathbb{N}$ is isomorphic to its product with itself $G \times G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, category-theory, free-groups

So let $G = \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$. We need to prove $G \cong G \times G$ (Aluffi ex. II.5.9). Here's my stab at it.

First, denote the set-function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $G$ that's the part of the free group construction as $j$.

Then, consider $G \times G$ as the (categorical) product of $G$ with itself (along with the projection functions $\pi_1,\pi_2$). Then there exists an unique morphism $\sigma$ in $\mathbf{Set}$ such that $j = \pi_1 \sigma = \pi_2 \sigma$.

Then, let's fix some arbitrary abelian group $H$ along with a set-function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow H$. By the corresponding universal property for $G$ being the free abelian group for $\mathbb{N}$, there exists an unique morphism $\varphi : G \rightarrow H$ such that $f = \varphi j$.

Now note that in $\mathbf{Ab}$ products coincide with coproducts, so there are injection functions $\iota_1, \iota_2 : G \rightarrow G \times G$. Also, by the universal property for coproducts, for the $H$ fixed above, there exists an unique $\sigma' : G \times G \rightarrow H$ such that $\varphi = \sigma' \iota_1 = \sigma' \iota_2$.

Combining all of the above, $f = \sigma' \iota_i \pi_j \sigma$ for $i, j \in \{ 1, 2 \}$. Now, further note that $\sigma' \iota_i \pi_j$ define a morphism $G \times G \rightarrow H$, which must coincide with $\sigma'$ by the universal property, so $f = \sigma' \sigma$.

And that's it! We've proven that there exists $\sigma : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow G \times G$ such that for every abelian $H, f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow H$ there exists an unique $\sigma' : G \times G \rightarrow H$ such that $f = \sigma' \sigma$, which is precisely the universal property that the free abelian group for $\mathbb{N}$ shall satisfy, which shows that $G \times G$ is *also* a free abelian group for $\mathbb{N}$.

---

Does the above seem reasonable? If so, does it generalize to free abelian groups for arbitrary sets? I don't think I've used any particular properties specific to $\mathbb{N}$. And are there better proofs?

Comment: If you replace $N$ with a singleton set, the F.A.G on $N$ looks like $Z$, but $G \times G$ is then $Z \times Z$, which is not $Z$. So either something about your argument uses the fact that $N$ is different from a singleton, or something about your argument is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, finite sets (and singletons in particular) made me worry, but I was not able to quickly disprove the existence of group isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, nor I was able to find a hole in my argument, hence the question.

Comment: A "better" proof that will become the evident way to handle this in the future is to note that the free abelian group functor, call it $F$, is a left adjoint and all left adjoints preserve colimits including coproducts. (Proving this is actually really easy if everything is formulated in terms of representability.) As you note, $\oplus$/$\times$/$+$ is a biproduct (i.e. simultaneously a product and a coproduct). Given $G=F(\mathbb N)$ we have $F(\mathbb N)+F(\mathbb N)\cong F(\mathbb N+\mathbb N)$. Then we use the set theoretic fact that $\mathbb N+\mathbb N\cong\mathbb N$.

Comment: So you're relying on $\mathbb{N} + \mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}$, while I'm not (or at least I don't see where I use it if I do). Now I'm pretty much convinced my proof is incomplete, but I don't know where.

Comment: $j$ is "the morphism from $\mathbb{N}$ to $G$". Which morphism is that? The edit didn't answer this question.

Comment: @logarithm I've updated my post, thanks!

Comment: @DerekElkins that's perhaps over my CT-fu (and the CT-fu that Aluffi builds and expects by this point).

Comment: @0xd34df00d And I my comment. If you are thinking of the function from $\mathbb{N}$ to generators of $G$, that is not a morphism.

Comment: Yep, I'm mixing up two different categories here ($\mathbf{Set}$ being the other). Perhaps "set-function" is a better word here.

Comment: @0xd34df00d Yes, hence the "in the future" part of my comment. That said, the results needed are surprisingly easy to prove. This is one of the nice things about category theory. There are quite a few relatively easy to prove theorems that apply to a huge variety of categories and problems. Given a categorical perspective, you realize that a large number of facts are not actually all that specific to groups or rings or whatever.

Comment: Another natural proof that would jump to mind "in the future" that doesn't rely on $\mathbb Z$ being freely generated is the following using the notion of copowers. Write $S\cdot H$ where $S$ is a set and $H$ an abelian group for $\coprod_{s\in S}H$, i.e. the coproduct of $S$-many copies of $H$. You can then easily show that, in general, $S_1\cdot H + S_2\cdot H \cong (S_1+S_2)\cdot H$. We use $S_1=S_2=\mathbb N$ with $H=\mathbb Z$ and, again, $\mathbb N+\mathbb N\cong\mathbb N$ to finish. One connection between the two arguments (which are distinct) is that $F(S)\cong S\cdot F(1)$.

Comment: The problem is then when you say that $\sigma'\iota_i\pi_i$ is $\sigma'$. $f$ and $\sigma$ are not in the same category in which $\sigma'$ is the unique morphism.

Comment: @logarithm awesome, thanks for spotting this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is wrong: you have not proved that $\sigma'$ is unique (and indeed it is not, for your choice of $\sigma$).  Your $\sigma'$ is unique with the property that $\varphi=\sigma'\iota_1=\sigma'\iota_2$ but there is no reason to believe it is also unique with the property that $f=\sigma'\sigma$.  In particular, note that the image of $\sigma$ generates only the diagonal subgroup of $G\times G$, not all of $G\times G$.  So, $\sigma'$ could behave in all sorts of ways on the elements of $G\times G$ that are not in the diagonal, and that will not disturb the equation $f=\sigma'\sigma$.

As mentioned in the comments, you do need to use something special about $\mathbb{N}$, namely that $\mathbb{N}\sqcup\mathbb{N}\cong\mathbb{N}$.  The idea is that $G\times G$, being also a coproduct of two copies of $G$, will be free on a coproduct of two copies of $\mathbb{N}$.

Alternatively, I would strongly encourage you to try to prove this just by concretely looking at what $G$ is as a set.  If you take $G$ to be the set of finite support sequences of elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, it's quite easy to write down an explicit isomorphism $G\cong G\times G$ (again, the key idea is to use $\mathbb{N}\sqcup\mathbb{N}\cong\mathbb{N}$, where this time the $\mathbb{N}$ shows up as the index set of the sequences).  Categorical proofs are valuable but it's also extremely valuable to have a concrete picture of what's going on (and that picture can help you find a categorical argument, if you want one).

Comment: Conversely, it is pretty mechanical to produce a concrete argument/construction given concrete representations of certain categorical structures, most particularly (co)limits in $\mathbf{Set}$. Given a concrete representation of $F(1)$, e.g. $\mathbb Z$, the arguments I gave can be mechanically unfolded to produce an explicit group isomorphism. Extracting the concrete content of "abstract nonsense" proofs is also a valuable exercise. This is probably more work than constructing it directly in this case but in more complex cases a direct solution may not be as forthcoming.

Comment: In addition to that, I've just realized I've proven $F^{Ab}(A \amalg B) \cong F^{Ab}(A) * F^{Ab}(B)$ earlier (shame on me for forgetting that!), and proving $F(S_1) \cong F(S_2)$ for $S_1 \cong S_2$ is trivial. The result follows immediately, and I guess that's what Derek mentioned in one of his comments.